# what is processEvents in a qt platform plugin supposed to do ?

Tags: qt, qt5

I am writing a new platform plugin for qt, i am trying to understand what is the "processEvents" virtual method supposed to do ? 
my requirement is that i receive events on a file descriptor and am supposed to translate them to qt gui events and pass them over to the qt. pls advise.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents :

> Processes all pending events for the calling thread according to the specified flags until there are no more events to process.
>
> You can call this function occasionally when your program is busy performing a long operation (e.g. copying a file).

This is probably not what you are looking for. Based on the short description of your problem, it seems to me that you want Linux's poll(). http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `QSocketNotifier` for this. Note that a `QSocketNotifier` takes a file handle only on Unix systems. On Windows, it takes a special winsock handle that is not a generalized HANDLE to an event object, neither is it a file handle. Don't worry about `processEvents`, it's not relevant to your problem.